# md-chr7y source file could not be found

Tags: fonts, errors, pdftex, miktex

I am trying to build a document with pdflatex (MikTeX) but it fails. It seems to be the used font on the title page. The error is as follows:

```
miktex-makemf: The md-chr7y source file could not be found.
Running ttf2pk.exe...
miktex-makepk: PK font md-chr7y could not be created.

!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file md-chr7y): Font md-chr7y at 572 not found
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

I found some information that this may be caused by a missing "charter" font packet. But this package was already installed and even reinstalling did not change anything.

Searching for "md-chr7y" I found three files:

```
MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\afm\mathdesign\mdbch\md-chr7y.afm
MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\type1\mathdesign\mdbch\md-chr7y.pfb
MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\tfm\mathdesign\mdbch\md-chr7y.tfm
```

**Update:**
I checked the available updmap.cfg files for the `Map mdbch.map` entry. I found the entry in the file `MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\config\updmap.cfg`.

What else can I do to fix this problem?

Comment: You have to rebuild the `pdftex.map` file. Pressing "Update FNDB" in the MiKTeX control panel may help.

Comment: @egreg I have already updated the FNDB - unfortunately it does not affect this problem.

Comment: You should have a `updmap.cfg` file on your system, in which the line `Map mdbch.map` should appear. If not, you have to edit the configuration running `initexmf --edit-config-file updmap` from a command shell in order to add that line and then `initexmf --mkmaps`. At least this is what the system should have done when adding the `charter` package. Some expert with MiKTeX may shed some light on this: it may be necessary to use the `--admin` option to the two commands.

Comment: Look in the log file and show the path that's used for the `pdftex.map` file.

Comment: @egreg The map entry was present but what missed was executing `initexmf --mkmaps`. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you add a font support package, the system should execute something similar to

```
initexmf --edit-config-file updmap
<add a line "Map mdbch.map">

initexmf --mkmaps
```

The `.map` file name can be different of course. If the `.map` file is present in the `updmap.cfg` file, then the second command hasn't be successful and issuing it from a command shell should solve the problem.

Comment: very helpfull
I am running miktex in windows 7.
If you update FNDB from the control panel as admin
and run the MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\updmap.exe
this would do the trick.
I wanted this for a cv template. Lifesavers guys!!
Thx

Comment: Thanks, @skywalker! That comment of yours just helped me (more than the answer that you commented on, though I would have tried the answer next if your point-and-click solution hadn't helped...)

Answer (score 2):

Under Windows just go to `C:\Program Files(x86)\MiKTeX2.9\miktex\bin` and run the file `updmap.exe`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Maybe `initex -mkmaps` would be better, but I guess it's very similar.