# jou class apa6 - problem with table

Tags: tables, fonts, apa6

I am running the short sample provided in apa6. [man] and [doc] class document mode work fine. But [jou] class is reporting problem (below). 
I've tried to isolate the problem. The problem arises with the table. Removing the table eliminates the problem. I am using MiKTeX 2.9 with TeXStudio. 
Any advice how to resolve so that table can be produced in jou class?

**I am trying to typeset the following example short sample from apa6:**

```
\documentclass[jou]{apa6} 
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa,sortcites=true,sorting=nyt,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}
\title{Sample APA-Style Document Using the \textsf{apa6} Package}
\shorttitle{test}
\author{Brian D. Beitzel}
\affiliation{SUNY Oneonta} 
\leftheader{Beitzel}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
We begin with \textcite{Shotton1989}.  We can also cite this work in
parenthesis, like this: \parencite{Shotton1989}. 
....
\section{Results}
Table \ref{tab:ComplexTable} contains some sample data.  Our
statistical prowess in analyzing these data is unmatched. 
\begin{table}[htbp]
\vspace*{2em}
  \begin{threeparttable}
\caption{A Complex Table} 
\label{tab:ComplexTable}
 \begin{tabular}{@{}lrrr@{}}         \toprule<br/> 
 Distribution type  & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Percentage of} & Total number \\   
                   & \multicolumn{2}{l}{targets with}  & of trials per  \\   
                   & \multicolumn{2}{l}{segment in}    & participant    \\ 
\cmidrule(r){2-3}   
                                    &  Onset  &  Coda            &       \\   \midrule   
    Categorical -- onset\tabfnm{a}  &    100  &     0            &  196     \\   
    Probabilistic                   &     80  &    20\tabfnm{*}  &  200     \\   
    Categorical -- coda\tabfnm{b}   &      0  &   100\tabfnm{*}  &  196     \\       \midrule  
    \end{tabular}   
    \begin{tablenotes}[para,flushleft]  
        {\small  
            \textit{Note.} All data are approximate.   
            \tabfnt{a}Categorical may be onset.   
            \tabfnt{b}Categorical may also be coda.  
            \tabfnt{*}\textit{p} < .05.  
            \tabfnt{**}\textit{p} < .01.  
         }  
    \end{tablenotes}  
  \end{threeparttable}
\end{table} 
\section{Discussion} 
This is a lengthy and erudite discussion.  It demonstrates amazing
skill in interpreting the results for the masses.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

**But when I compile it with LaTeX I get this error message:**

```
Trying to make PK font rtxr at 540 DPI...  
Running miktex-makemf.exe... miktex-makemf: The rtxr source file could not be found.       
Running ttf2pk.exe...  
miktex-makepk: PK font rtxr could not be created.  
Process exited with error(s)
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they're marked as a code sample. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (`{}`) or hit Ctrl+K.

Comment: See if [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/48568/3345) helps. In short, as administrator, update the MiKTeX FNDB and run updmap.exe.

Comment: The MiKTeX FND8 was up to date. So, I just ran updmap.exe. It now produces the tables without errors. (I'm new to this forum and dont know how to upvote or indicate this question has been answered)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was a localized issue solved in the comments by running updmap.exe.